# CLT and Determining Normality Without Dataset

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I am somewhat new to statistics and for my degree, I am required to take a statistics course. We have recently started to look into sampling distributions, point estimators, statistical intervals, and the central limit theorem (CLT). One thing that I cannot seem to understand is how we can determine normality - or the distribution-type in general - without a dataset. Normality or large enough sample sizes to induce normality is, of course, a requirement for using CLT, so being able to determine if a distribution will be normal is extremely important to being able to apply CLT.

To that end, I have taken a problem from my most recent homework assignment, I have modified the example scenario, and the values of everything except the sample size (*n*):

> Based on a recent study, it was found that on average, the human body should consume 2.48 L when performing strenuous outdoor activity. It was further noted that the standard deviation of water consumed among the study's participants was 0.5305 L.
>
> If 10 random study participants are sampled, what is the probability that they consumed between 2.1518 and 2.8082 L? First determine if Central Limit Theorem applies, explain why it does or does not apply, and then solve only if CLT can be used.

Just given the mean (2.48 L), the standard deviation (0.5305 L), and sample size (n = 10), how would one go about determining if the distribution is normal or normal enough to use CLT?

In my course textbook, it is recommended that sample size, n, be greater than or equal to 30; however, it is further explained that n can be less this than thirty, but thirty is recommended because it is large enough to almost always normalize a distribution.

Comment: Homework problems require the self-study tag.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, ahh my bad. Thanks for the heads up. Question is not identical to the assignment, but I will add it for good measure.

Comment: Unless this are participants in a water consumption competition, liters consumed will not wary that much between participants, and there cannot be realy extreme values.  So i guess a normal approx can be good.  That $n=10$ only should be no problem.